# Navigation Drawer + Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation-drawer

estou com um problema em juntar Navigation Drawer como o Google Maps. Eu quero que o google seja meu fragment inicial e quero que está na lista do Navigation Drawer como um item, mas está haver uma pequeno empecilho. Vou tentar explicar da melhor maneira e espero que vocês me ajudem.

Na Classe do `MainFragment`(Codigo do Google Maps) pede que eu importe `android.app.Fragment` mas quando vou pra `MainActivity` pede que na classe `MainFragment` seja importado `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

**Main Fragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    fragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    LatLng marker = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 13));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Hello Google Maps!").position(marker));
}
```

Com o `android.app.Fragment` não tem nenhum erro, mas quando importo `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` o erro acontece em `(MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);`

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Set the fragment initially
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Com importe `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`em `MainFragment` a `MainActivity` não dá erro, mas se importo `android.app.Fragment` o erro acontece em(onde tá em negrito):
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, **fragment**);

Basicamente em cada lado eles pedem importes diferentes, eu sei entendo onde tá o erro, mas não sei como conserta-lo.

Comment: Lari, teria como você postar o stacktrace do erro? Isso ajudaria na solução do seu problema

Comment: Se importar `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` tanto em `MainFragment` como em `MainActivity` não funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi da pergunta você fez fazer funcionar.

> Com importe android.support.v4.app.Fragmentem MainFragment a MainActivity não dá erro

porém antes de tudo você tem que saber a diferença entre esses dois imports
o **(1)android.support.v4.app.Fragment** e o **(2)android.app.Fragment**

1- é uma class de **suporte a Fragment** criado para dá compatibilidades a versões menores que **API11**

2- é uma class do **Fragment na versão nativa**, foi introduzida no Android3( **API 11** ).

Você agora tem que saber se seu app vai funcionar em **versões menores que API11** se sim modifique sua class MainFragment para **herdar de android.support.v4.app.Fragment** e pronto , caso contrario use **como o padrão android.app.Fragment**
e na sua **MainAcvitity troque o getSupportFragmentManager** pois você **não** vai está dando suporte a versão menor API11 para.

```
MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction1.replace(R.id.prefsfragment, fragment);
transaction1.commit();
```

Comment: Oi Alessandro, teria como eu entrar em contato contigo ? Sou nova na programação em android e tenho algumas duvidas que não sei com quem tirar, se possível agradeço muito, meu email é Larissadesouza16@live.com.